# Journal mode logcat entry when opening database

Tags: android, sqlite

Each time I open a database in my app either on a real device or avd I see the following LogCat entry:

```
E/SQLiteLog﹕ (5) statement aborts at 2: [PRAGMA journal_mode=PERSIST]
```

These are Lollipop devices and I understand that PERSIST has been used since API 16, but it looks as if something is not quite right.

The database works perfectly (as far as I can tell) after the open.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when I tried to use write-ahead logging `db.enableWriteAheadLogging()` in `onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db)`:

```
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.enableWriteAheadLogging();
    super.onConfigure(db);
}
```

Because write-ahead logging cannot be used with read-only databases therefore, you must use `setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled(true)`:

```
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled(true);
    super.onConfigure(db);
}
```

Or use `db.enableWriteAheadLogging()` only in `getWritableDatabase()`:

```
@Override
public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = super.getWritableDatabase();
    db.enableWriteAheadLogging();
    return db;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it when I stopped the Database from handling multiple transactions. delete `database.enableWriteAheadLogging()` or use `database.disableWriteAheadLogging()`

Comment: I need the database to handle multiple updates. It looks like this is a minor bug.

Comment: I think the problem happens, when you try to access the database from different threads.